# Replicate my KeyboardListener in all my screens in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an app that works with a scanner. I'm reading the scan just through text. This seems to happen in almost every screen of my app. I tried to control this through my MyApp widget, but I have no idea how to call the current screen (widget) to process the barcode according this current screen. I'm encapsulating everything through a KeyboardListener. is there a better approach for this problem? I was thinking also to create a abstract class holding all the scanner functionality inside.

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:scanner/models/beep.dart';
import 'package:scanner/screens/dashboard.dart';
import 'package:scanner/screens/location_info.dart';
import 'package:scanner/screens/login.dart';
import 'package:scanner/screens/relocation.dart';

void main() {
    runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
    const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
    static final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

    @override
    _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
    List<LogicalKeyboardKey> keys = [];
    dynamic screen;
    late Future<Beep> futureUser;

    Future<Beep> fetchBeep(String code) async {
        try {
            final response = await http.get(Uri.parse('http://192.168.224.8:8000/restapi/beeps/${code}/'));     
            if (response.statusCode == 200) {
                return Beep.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
            } else {
                throw Exception('Failed to load beep');
            }
        } catch (e) {
            debugPrint(e.toString());
            throw Exception('Failed!!!!!');
        }
    }
    
    String _getBarcode(List<LogicalKeyboardKey> keys) {
        String code = '';
        for (var key in keys) {
            if (key.keyLabel != 'Shift Left') {
                code += key.keyLabel;
            }
        }
        return code;
    }

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return KeyboardListener(
            autofocus: true,
            focusNode: FocusNode(), 
            onKeyEvent: (event) {
                if (event is KeyUpEvent) {
                    final key = event.logicalKey;
                    if (key != LogicalKeyboardKey.enter) {
                        setState(() {
                            keys.add(key);
                        });
                    }
                    else {
                        String barcode = _getBarcode(keys);
                        Future<Beep> b = fetchBeep(barcode);
                        b.then((value) {
                            keys = [];
                            debugPrint('HERE I MUST CALL THE SCREEN !!!');
                            // screen.process(value);

                        });
                    }
                }
            },
            child: MaterialApp(
                title: 'Protonic',
                theme: ThemeData(
                    primaryColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 17, 6, 65),
                ),
                initialRoute: '/',
                onGenerateRoute: (settings) {
                    String? name = settings.name;
                    if (name == '/') {
                        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => const LoginScreen());
                    }
                    if (name == '/dashboard') {
                        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => const DashboardScreen());
                    }
                    if (name == '/relocation') {
                        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => const RelocationScreen());
                    }
                    if (name == '/location_info') {
                        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => const LocationInfoScreen()); 
                    }
                    return null;
                },
            )
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question was not clear to me. But what I understand is that you can do whatever you want with StateManagement. As far as I can see you are not using any StateManagement.

For example, if you use Getx, you will create 1 controller. o You will be able to call the Controller from anywhere and use what you need.

Comment: You should probably put your `KeyboardListener` into a component and add this specific component to all your screens.

Comment: @LOLWTFasdasdasdad yeah, how can I do that? Do you have some guidlines? Thanks

Comment: @ruben you can take a look here https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatelessWidget-class.html. Create a new widget which returns the `KeyboardListener`. You could also extend a `KeyboardListener` instead of `StatelessWidget` for example.